# Unit root tests from different python modules produce different results on the same time series

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, pmdarima

`ADFTest()` from `pmdarima` and `adfuller()` from `statsmodels` produce different
`p-values` when given as input the same time series. Why is this happening?

For example:

```
from pmdarima.arima.stationarity import ADFTest
adf_test = ADFTest()
p_val1, should_diff = adf_test.should_diff(series.arrivals)
print(p_val1)

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
ad_fuller_result = adfuller(series.arrivals)
p_val2 = ad_fuller_result[1]
print(p_val2)
```

Output:

```
p_val1 = 0.05134192567802651
p_val2 = 0.3632790519019964
```

Comment: hi, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: do you need me to give you the series also?

Comment: The most likely difference is due to the deterministic terms included.  `ADFTest` uses a data dependent choice of the deterministic terms, which is not a standard choice. A quick inspection of the code in pmdarima's `ADFTest` suggests it is wrong since it does not determine the critical value based on the number of deterministic terms included.  I would not trust this function. A third, and mostly clean sheet implementation, is available in the `arch` package (which I maintain), although it is closer to statsmodels in terms of choices.